# authentication error in sending mail from yahoo in c# windows application

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, smtp, yahoo

i am trying to send email from my software using the smtp of yahoo but it shows the following error
"The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.1 Authentication required".

I know about the less secure apps setting in google but i don't know about the settings in yahoo. the same code runs fine with the gmail account credentials. here is the code for reference.

```
string EmailFrom = "test@yahoo.com";
        string EmailTo = "test@gmail.com";
        string PassWord = "test123";
        string EmailHost = "smtp.mail.yahoo.com";
        string status = "";
        string Body = "";

        MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();

        message.From = new MailAddress(EmailFrom);
        message.To.Add(new MailAddress(EmailTo));
        message.Subject = "Auto Backup at test" ;
        message.Body = "Backup has been taken at test on" + DateTime.Now;
        Body = "Backup has been taken at test on" + DateTime.Now;
        smtp.Port = 587;
        smtp.Host = EmailHost;
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
        smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(EmailFrom, PassWord);
        smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        //ServiceLogLibrary.WriteErrorlog("Step:5");
        //Library.WriteErrorlog("Before sending mail");
        smtp.Send(message);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to go to

1. [Go to your "Account security" settings.](https://login.yahoo.com/account/security#less-secure-apps)
2. Select Allow apps that use less secure sign in.
3. To deny or turn off app access, deselect the undesired app.

Source:[Temporarily allow or deny access to apps using older security sign in](https://help.yahoo.com/kb/SLN27791.html)

[image: [Screenshot]]

Comment: Hi @mohit : i have accepted the answer. you can also help me by upvoting the question. thanks

Answer (score 4):

Just providing some more information here as things have changed a little since the accepted answer was posted.

1. Go to the account security settings (https://login.yahoo.com/account/security)
2. Scroll to the bottom and search for the "Manage app passwords" heading as shown below and click it to add a new app.

[image]

3. Select an app type and generate the password. For API apps, use "Other App".

[image]

4. Use this password instead of your standard mailbox password when sending emails via your SmtpClient.