# why email is not sending here?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a code for sending emails:

```
public static bool SendEmail(
    string fromEmail, string toEmail,
    string subject, string body,
    bool isBodyHtml = false, bool isThrowException = false)
{
    var message = new MailMessage(fromEmail, toEmail)
    {
        IsBodyHtml = isBodyHtml,
        Subject = subject,
        Body = body,
    };

    using (var client = new SmtpClient())
    {
        try
        {
            client.Send(message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (isThrowException)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

In `web.config` I have:

```
  <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp>
        <network host="smtp.bizmail.yahoo.com" port="25" enableSsl="true" userName=helpdesk@global.com" password="@cr123" defaultCredentials="true"/>
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
</configuration>
```

Now I don't have any exception, still mail is not receiving at the other end.
I am able to login to yahoo.com by my credentials.
still

```
client->credentils->domain=""
client->ServicePoint = 'client.ServicePoint' threw an exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException'
```

What's gone wrong with it?

The code was working well... before 1 month, I didn't change a single line, what's gone wrong?

Comment: Is this your real username and password !!

Comment: Not any more - I just removed it in case :P

Comment: Where the `<smtp>` actually located in the Config?

Comment: no.........its not actual username and password, but i am able to login b actual credentials in yahoo.com

Comment: But it is now in edit history, update your username and password in your system

Comment: smtp is in web.config

Comment: I mean is that under this `<configuration>
 <system.net>
        <mailSettings>` ??

Comment: yes it is un-lucky

Comment: See your `if(isThrowException){...}` Can you not throw an actual base `Exception` object. You can just rethrow the original exception with just `throw` on its own and you don't lose all the additional information in the exception as you do when you create a new exception object (especially as you're also not encapsulating the original as an `InnerException`)

Comment: try setting client.Host, client.Port, and credentials directly in your code

Comment: anyway ia m returning true, but i found some exception in variable ex.

Comment: @mcNets client.host , port is coming properly but credentials not coming

Comment: Isn't the problem related somehow to the fact that you use username and password and still have the defaultCredentials set to "true"? Shouldn't you set defaultCredentials to "false"?

Comment: ok i made it as true... @JakubRusilko, now i anm not getting any exception. but still mail is not recieving...

Comment: try port 586. may be it works

Comment: I think you should reset your password, if you did use the real username and password in the original question anyone can view it in the edit history.

Comment: @hildasonica You should change your email password **now**

Comment: @SURJEETSINGHBisht port changed, not worked.

Comment: @Pikoh its already enabled.. right?

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer why should i change?

Comment: @hildasonica Because now everybody knows it.

Comment: @bolt19 in history also i gave wrong credentials , no worries...

Comment: the code was working well.. before 1 month, i didnt change single line, whats gone wrong? please help

Comment: @hildasonica: did u enable [less secure sign in](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40583714/3796048)

Comment: its already enabled. @MohitShrivastava

Comment: I got what went wrong... thanks all....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First up all thanks to all who tried to help you.

As in the Question i mentioned there is an error while creating a new object of smtp.

smtp will read the web.config and create an object with respect to web.config.
So i came to know that the problem is with web.config .I was also sure that there is nothing wrong with the C# code. so i analysed the web.config and found some filter.

```
    <filter level="TraceEventType.Error" />
```

basically i used this for removing error message for azure version.

which is causing problem for Serverpoint while creating an object of smtp. 
So I just removed the line. and it worked fine.

I got to know not only smtp tag, other tags in web.config file will also effect the current problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add connection properties and credentials to your code:

```
NetworkCredentials Credencials = new NetworkCredential(SmtpUsername, SmtpPassword);

client.Host = SmtpHost;
client.Port = SmtpPort; 
client.Credentials = Credencials;
```

Comment: no need of this host and port is coming properly without that...credential also, but no domain is cominng, dont know whether it is needed or not. but still mail not recieved.